# google maps api v3 marker click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

not sure where the problem lies with this, i created a google map with custom markers a few months back using v3 of the api. the info windows were working back then.

i have been porting it onto a new site and cant get the info window to open, the js alerts in the right point when creating the click event but the click event does not fire all i can do is drag the map, so i looked at the last site i did, and its not working there either now.

so not sure how to fix this, the code i have to create ther info window is as follows:

```
markersArray.push(marker);
        markersPosArray.push(myLatLng);
        // Wrapping the event listener inside an anonymous function
        // that we immediately invoke and passes the variable i to.
        (function(myData, marker) {
            alert('creating listener for: '+marker);
            // Creating the event listener. It now has access to the values of
            // myData and marker as they were during its creation
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                //create thecontent for the infowindow
                alert('creating info window');
                var content = 'hello there'; //createContent(myData);
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });


        })(myData, marker);
```

maybe something has changed in the api that i am unaware off?

the testpage can be seen at: http://www.disposalknowhow.com/locator.php
In the locator use the following to obtain results:

type: electrical/electronics - item: computers - radius: 100 - postcode: n11hl

the previous one i did that is not working either now can be seen at: http://www.focus-on-plants.com/locator_iconed.php
(can use any parameters here in the form)

UPDATE:

in reply to treffys answer:

the infowindow is defined when i create the map:

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.470, -0.00);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var gotIcons = false;
    var iconImageArray = {image:{}, size:{}, sizeX:{}, sizeY:{}, origin:{}, originX:{}, originY:{}, anchorpoint:{}, anchorpointX:{}, anchorpointY:{}};
    var iconShadowArray = {image:{}, size:{}, sizeX:{}, sizeY:{}, origin:{}, originX:{}, originY:{}, anchorpoint:{}, anchorpointX:{}, anchorpointY:{}};
    var iconShapeArray = {poly:{}, coord:{}};
    var myIconArray = {icon:{}, shadow:{}, shape:{}}
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var markersArray = []; // to store out markers
    var markersPosArray = []; // to store lat/lang of markers for zooming function
    var markersInfoArray = [];
    // MAP OPTIONS
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM
        },
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
        },
        scaleControl: true,
        scaleControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
        }
    };//end map options
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("loc_map"), myOptions);
```

Comment: Where does the variable `infowindow` come from in your click event callback?

Comment: hmm thats a good question, i think youve found my error, i'll try your code below and report back, thanks

Comment: checked the script and infowindow is defined when i create the map, see my update in the question

Comment: seems to work based on the code to your site http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/4fZbF/

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following code to display an info bubble:

```
var info_pane = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: info,
                    disableAutoPan: false,
                    maxWidth: '300px'
                });
info_pane.open(map, marker);
```

Comment: tried using this code instead, but still no infowindow, it alerts that the listener is being created for each icon

Comment: Hmm... I am not sure. I can't give you a link to the site I am using that code on as it is yet to go live unfortunately. Looking at your code nothing is jumping out immediately.

Comment: am stuck too, as i said the codeworked when i did a site a few months back which now doesn't show the info window, no errors are generated so hard to know where to look, the alert just before the creation of the on-click works so i think the problem is somwhere within the onclick listener, but the code looks ok to me...

Comment: @Dizzy actually you dont' need to use closure for the onclick event you can basically set the `infowindow.open(map, this);` and remove the closure http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/4fZbF/